# Деревья отрезков. Непересекающиеся отрезки

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Имеется задачка [(исходное условие)](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=597&chapterid=753#)

> Отрезок целочисленной прямой длины N разбит на единичные отрезки,
>   которые пронумерованы от 1 до N.
>
> Их объединяют в группы по следующим правилам:
>
> 1. Несколько подряд идущих отрезков, ни один из которых не принадлежит ни одной из групп, могут быть объединены в группу.
> 2. Любая ранее созданная группа может быть уничтожена, при этом входившие в нее отрезки больше не относятся ни к какой группе и могут
>      впоследствии быть отнесены к другим группам.
>
> Видно, что любой отрезок всегда находится не более, чем в одной
>   группе.
>
> Каждую группу можно идентифицировать парой чисел: номером первого и
>   номером последнего отрезка, входящего в группу.
>
> Первоначально нет ни одной группы.
>
> **Входные данные:** Первая строка входных данных содержит число N –
>   количество отрезков и число K – количество запросов (1 ≤ N, K ≤10^5).
>   Далее идет K строчек, содержащих запросы к структуре данных. Каждый
>   запрос начинается с числа 1 (запрос на создание группы) или 2 (запрос
>   на удаление группы). После числа 1 указывается два других числа l и r
>   (1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ N), после числа 2 указывается одно число i (1 ≤ i ≤ N).
>
> **Выходные данные:** Для каждого запроса типа 1 необходимо отрезки с
>   номерами от l до r объединить в группу. Если все эти отрезки не входят
>   ни в одну группу, запрос считается удачным и программа должна вывести
>   1. Если хотя бы один из этих отрезков уже относится к какой-то группе, запрос считается неудачным, объединение не производится и программа
>   выводит 0.
>
> Для каждого запроса типа 2 необходимо удалить группу, в которую входит
>   отрезок с номером i, при этом программа должна вывести два числа:
>   номер первого и последнего отрезка, входящих в удаляемую группу. Если
>   отрезок с номером i не относится ни к одной группе, программа должна
>   вывести два нуля.

она решается с помощью дерева отрезков. Я знаю как устроенна эта структура данных и могу применять её для поиска min/max, суммы и т.д. на отрезках, но не могу понять, как её применить к конкретно этой задаче.

Подскажите, как можно адаптировать стандартный RMQ/RSQ под эту задачу.

Вот например решение задачи о максимальном элементе на отрезке с помощью деревьев отрезков (RMQ):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm> 
int t[4 * 100000];
int a[100000];
#define INF 100000007
void build(int v, int vl, int vr, int a[]) {
    if (vl == vr) {
        t[v] = a[vl]; 
        return;
    }
    int vm = vl + (vr - vl) / 2;
    build(2 * v + 1, vl, vm, a);
    build(2 * v + 2, vm + 1, vr, a);
    t[v] = max(t[2 * v + 1], t[2 * v + 2]);
}

int query(int v, int vl, int vr, int l, int r) {
    if (r < vl || vr < l)
        return 0;
    if (l <= vl && vr <= r)
        return t[v];
    int vm = vl + (vr - vl) / 2;
    int ql = query(2 * v + 1, vl, vm, l, r);
    int qr = query(2 * v + 2, vm + 1, vr, l, r);
    return max(ql, qr);
}

int main()
{
    int N,Q,l,r;
    cin >> N; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    build(0,0,N-1,a);
    cin >> Q;
    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
        cin >> l >> r;
        int p = query(0, 0, N - 1, l - 1, r - 1);

        cout << p << "\n";
    }
}
```

Зача решаеться такой же структурой данных, как в выше указанном примере

Вот [здесь](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree) расписано всё про дерево отрезков.

P.S.
Написал на питоне, но решение почти не рабочее. (7 баллов из 100)

```
def build(v, vl, vr):
    if vl == vr:
        t[v] = [1,[a[vl]]]
        return
    vm = vl + (vr - vl) // 2 
    build(2 * v + 1, vl, vm)
    build(2 * v + 2, vm + 1, vr)
    t[v] = [2,[vl,vr]]

def find(v, vl, vr, e):
    #print(v,vl,vr,e)
    if vl==vr:
        return v
    vm = vl + (vr - vl) // 2
    if t[2*v+2][0] and t[2*v+1][0]:
        if t[2*v+2][1][0]<=e:
            return find(2*v+2,vm+1,vr,e) 
        else:
            return find(2*v+1,vl,vm,e)
    else:
        return v

def remove(v, vl, vr, e):
    e = find(v, vl, vr, e)
    if t[e][0]==1:
        return [0,0]
    t[2*e+1][0]=1
    t[2*e+2][0]=1
    return [t[e][1][0]+1, t[e][1][1]+1]

def merge(v, vl, vr, e1, e2):
    e1 = find(v, vl, vr, e1)
    e2 = find(v, vl, vr, e2)
    if t[e1][0]==1 and t[e2][0]==1:
        t[e1][0]=0
        t[e2][0]=0
        return 1
    return 0

N,K = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a = list(range(N)) 
t = [[0,[]] for i in range(4*N)]
build(0,0,N-1)

for i in range(K):
    q = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    if q[0]==1:
        print(merge(0, 0, N-1, q[1]-1, q[2]-1))
    else:
        r = remove(0, 0, N-1, q[1]-1)
        print(r[0],r[1])
```

Алгоритм основывается на том, что объединять можно только рядом стоящие отрезки, которые не принадлежат ни одной группе => объединять можно только отрезки из одного элемента.

Функция find - обычный поиск по бинарному дереву за log, который не учитывает отрезки длиной меньше 1, merge - просто проверяет длины отрезков и если они оба равны 1, то приравнивает длины к 0 => функция find будет останавливаться на их предке, а предок и будет являться их слиянием. Ну и функция remove - просто восстанавливает длины единичных отрезков, чтобы при поиске они вновь становились видимыми, что равносильно удалению их слияния.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как мне кажется, то достаточно хранить множество пар начала и концов групп. А компаратор проверят пересечение этих пар по правилу: достаточно, что если координата(начало или конец) одной из группы принадлежит диапазону из координат другой группы. Но если вам нельзя использовать stl алгоритмы (Хотя вы подключили заголовок), то это решение не подходит :)

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать как эта задача решается именно деревом отрезков, так как это позволит находить ответ быстрее линейного времени.

Comment: STL использовать можно

Comment: У меня эта задача на 70, как на 100 хз

Answer (score 2):

Действительно можно использовать почти обычное дерево отрезков.

Для решения задачи ваше дерево должно уметь:

1. Проверять, что все элементы (будем так называть единичные отрезки) на заданном отрезке [L, R] не принадлежат ни одному отрезку.
2. Объединять все элементы на отрезке [L, R] в один отрезок или удалять их из него = красить их в цвет нового отрезка или в "белый".
3. Находить, в цвет какого отрезка сейчас покрашен элемент i.

Для этого создадим массив пар, который будет хранить границы отрезка с цветом-индексом.

Далее нужно реализовать ДО, поддерживающее вышеописанные операции. Можно заметить, что если ДО поддерживает операции суммы на отрезке и присваивания на отрезке, то все три операции легко реализовать:

1. "Самостоятельные" неокрашенные элементы будут изначально иметь цвет 0, а значит если все элементы от L до R неокрашенные, то сумма их цветов также равна нулю.
2. Окрасим в 0 при разрушении или в цвет номера запроса при объединении.
3. Сумма цветов от i до i.

Конкретную реализацию такого дерева можно найти, если немного погуглить (скорее всего, придется самостоятельно объединить два вида деревьев [прибавление-отрезок:сумма-отрезок] и [присвоение-отрезок:запрос-элемент]).

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, есть проблема в терминологии. В этой задаче требуется настоящее дерево отрезков - segment tree, interval tree, которое действительно содержит именно отрезки/интервалы в упорядоченном виде, и имеет операции для добавления, удаления, объединения, проверки пересечения интервалов, поиск интервала, которому принадлежит точка. Имея такое дерево, решить данную задачу будет нетрудно.

А то, что процитировано - олимпиадники  так называют структуру данных, которая позволяет быстро проводить некие операции над целым интервалом. Здесь она кажется ни к чему.

Убогое описание [Segment Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) в англ. вики

А вот связанная с ней [статья в русской вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) относится как раз ко второй структуре

Comment: Я попробовал реализовать алгоритм на основе "настоящего" дерева отрезков, с хранением левой и правой границы отрезка (код и пояснение добавил в пост). Подскажите где я ошибаюсь.